# using powershell to remove all files with size smaller than 100gb

Tags: powershell, command-line, command, command-line-interface

I want to use powershell to remove all files with size smaller than 100gb and used

`ls | where {$_.Length -lt 100gb} | Remove-Item -Force-Recurse`

But got this error

```
Remove-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Force-Recurse'.
At line:1 char:48
+ ls | where {$_.Length -lt 100gb} | Remove-Item -Force-Recurse
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

What has gone wrong here?

Comment: You do not want to use recurse because it will apply to both folders and files and remove items twice.  Try :  get-childitem -file -recursive | where {$_.Length -lt 100gb} | foreach {Remove-Item -Force $_.Fullname }

Comment: There should be a space between `-Force` and `-Recurse`

Comment: Good Lord, answer is written in the casted error message.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a matter of adding an extra space between parameters. Also make sure you really want to recursively delete the files from all subfolders:

```
 ls | where {$_.Length -lt 100gb} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```